# How many quotes to use when calling cmd from vbs? mklink example

Tags: vbscript, cmd

just a quick question. I am trying to execute the following cmd command from vbs:

```
mklink /j "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\FIEBIG\bin" "%Programfiles(x86)%\fiebig-team\fticclient\bin"
```

with the following code:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd.exe mklink /j ""%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\FIEBIG\bin"" ""Programfiles(x86)%\fiebig-team\fticclient\bin"" "
```

However, no matter what I've tried with adding or excluding quotes, it still does not work.

Can you please help with this, 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `CMD.EXE`, do you?

```
strCommand = "mklink /j"
strCommand = strCommand & " "
strCommand = strCommand & Chr(34) & "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\FIEBIG\bin" & Chr(34)
strCommand = strCommand & " "
strCommand = strCommand & Chr(34) & "%Programfiles(x86)%\fiebig-team\fticclient\bin" & Chr(34)

objShell.Run strCommand
```

BTW, here's a debugging trick I use to make sure I get the proper command line. Use an `InputBox()` and pass your command string as the 3rd parameter. That allows you to copy and paste it to your command prompt window.

```
InputBox "", "", strCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help. I am really into software packaging and just starting coding. How does that look to you?

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run
strCommand = "mklink /j"
strCommand = strCommand & " "
strCommand = strCommand & Chr(34) & "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\FIEBIG\bin" & Chr(34)
strCommand = strCommand & " "
strCommand = strCommand & Chr(34) & "%Programfiles(x86)%\fiebig-team\fticclient\bin" & Chr(34)

objShell.Run strCommand
```

Comment: If it works, it looks great. :) You have an extra, unneeded `objShell.run` statement, though, on line 2. Instead of posting it as an asnwer, though, add your code to your original question. And if you have any further questions you can ask there, or create a new question.